# Azure Data Flow / Data factory Error Handling

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

What I want to achieve is to include error handling in azure data Flow if an error occurs while transferring the rows it should not fail it process the other rows and save the id of the row which occurred error in a text file or log

Example:

Let suppose we have 10 rows to sink in a table and somehow we got an error on row 5, but I want the data-flow to skip that row but insert remaining 9 rows and save the id of the row which created an error in a text file or a SQL Table

Answer (score 1):

You can set that fault tolerance option in the copy activity to achieve this .

[image]

In addition to above, you can also achieve the same in Mapping Data Flow of Azure Data Factory with error row handling concept using Conditional split in your Data Flow.

Please refer to this MS doc which has a sample on how to split/log the error rows based on specific condition : [Error Row handling in Mapping Data Flow of Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/how-to-data-flow-error-rows)

Also please refer to below MSDN thread where a similar implementation was explained for handling error rows in Data flow.

MSDN thread: [Mapping Data Flows Error Handling](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f7a14806-8e2a-4d82-8311-bea702848f70/mapping-data-flows-error-handling?forum=AzureDataFactory)